# Mac Catalyst UITitleBar covers the UI -- how to resolve?

Tags: ios, macos, mac-catalyst

When running an iPad Mac Catalyst iPad on macos, there is a title bar, which I don't mind. But it covers part of the UI, and to compensate I should shift my UI down by the height of that bar. I cannot find a way to find that height anywhere. I've tried querying it and its `NSToolbar` properties but nothing gives me this basic information.

I can hide the toolbar itself with no problem, using this:

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        if let titlebar = windowScene.titlebar {
            titlebar.titleVisibility = .hidden
            titlebar.toolbar = nil
        }
#endif
```

This almost resolves the problem, as most of the UI is accessible once that title bar is gone, but the three upper left controls to close and zoom the window are still on top of UI elements.

How do you normally handle this problem?

Comment: Sounds like your UI doesn't use the `safeAreaInsets`

Comment: @jnpdx I think you are right! Make that an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your UI to avoid the title bar and other window chrome, it needs to respect `safeAreaInsets`, which tell your UI what area is safe to be drawn on without being covered by system UI.

Comment: The problem is that safeAreaInsets are all zero!